# Openshift jobssas 7 cloud was building the war but not deploying it

Tags: java, maven, deployment, jboss7.x, openshift

Openshift was building the war but not deploying it

[image]

If the one wants to deploy the generated war, it must be copied by command

`cp app-root/runtime/repo/target/GameStore-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war app-root/dependencies/jbossas/deployments/ROOT.war`

How to copy the generated war automatically ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the openshift jbossas7 cloud require the presence of `pom.xml` to build the code after push it throw `git push` command.
Secondly, to auto deploy the generated war after building it write in `pom.xml`

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <!-- When built in OpenShift the 'openshift' profile will be used when 
            invoking mvn. -->
        <!-- Use this profile for any OpenShift specific customization your app 
            will need. -->
        <!-- By default that is to put the resulting archive into the 'deployments' 
            folder. -->
        <!-- http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-building-for-different-environments.html -->
        <id>openshift</id>
        <build>
            <finalName>GameStore</finalName>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>deployments</outputDirectory>
                        <warName>ROOT</warName>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```